# Prevent Windows 2003 blue screen upon boot after changing to RAID?

Tags: boot, raid, bsod, windows-server-2003, hardware-raid

Here's what's happening.

I havent been using hardware RAID on my motherboard, but since I got new disks today I changed from normal SATA to RAID and rebooted.

I set up the RAID, three disks, one of them for the OS, the two other RAIDED as one. Rebooted.

The Windows Server 2003 loading-logo shows up for a second and then, it hasn't even faded in completely, I get a blue screen, which lasts for 0.5 sec and then the computer auto-reboots and does the same thing again forever.

I thought this RAID stuff should be handled automatically by the hardware but seems like WinServer2003 is missing somehing.

If I change back to not using RAID but normal SATA mode I can boot back into the OS again.

What the hell should I do to not get the BSOD??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the registry values accordingly. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976#method1 for detail. Essentially, the 'Start' values for

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Msahci
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\IastorV
```

should be set to 0.

[image: Registry Value]

Use caution when changing registry values as an incorrect setting could cause further problems.

Comment: Neither of those two keys (Msahci or IastorV) exists. Do I can't do it.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Msahci is the registry folder. The key is Start.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant none of those two folders exists.

Comment: I think I'll just try software RAID then... since it doesn't work and RAID0 with software should be almost as good as RAID0 with hardware.

Comment: Ok, perhaps if you could provide the BSOD error message we can find an alternate solution. Try hitting F8 during boot and choose the option for not rebooting on system failure (not the exact wording) and write down the error code.

Comment: Do you have the drivers loaded for the RAID controller?

Comment: Probably not, thing is I installed the OS when the motherboard was not in RAID mode. Come to think of it I think I installed the OS on a different motherboard that didn't even have support for hardware RAID.

Comment: One last thing to try would be install the drivers for the hardware RAID controller when booted using the SATA BIOS mode and reboot using RAID mode.

Comment: I think I'll just go with software RAID. I'm not sure where to get those drivers, I've misplaced any CDs I got and don't have Internet connection for the server right this moment (nor a CD reader connected). Since I've read that software RAID0 is pretty much just as good as hardware RAID0 I'll just go with that. The CPU on the server was hardly ever going over 50% anyways.